# How about "this" as a type?

Tags: kotlin, language-features

I will simplify the problem that got me to this point, but I was thinking about this block of code :

```
abstract class A {
    fun myCustomApply(block: A.() -> Unit): A {
        this.block()  // block() would have the same effect
        // Do something else here
        return this
    }
}

class B : A() {
    fun anotherFunction() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This code looks (and is) ok. But consider the following snippet :

```
fun doSomethingVeryUseful(): B /* Won't work */ {
    val b = B()
    return b.myCustomApply {
        anotherFunction()  // Nope
    }
}
```

Here, the compiler will complain, for two reasons, that may not seem obvious at first glance. First of all, `myCustomApply`'s `block` parameter was declared with type `A.() -> Unit`, so we can't call `anotherFunction()` within its scope, because it was declared in class B.
Then, it appears that `doSomethingVeryUseful`'s return type was declared as B, but `myCustomApply` returns A, so we have to use an `as A` cast.

Both errors are logical, because the compiler can't guess by itself "Oh yeah, the return type is A but it always returns `this`, so it is perfectly fine to do that !", but these are kinda painful to handle properly because I personnally can't think of a proper workaround.

Of course, you could do something like this :

```
abstract class A

class B : A() {
    fun anotherFunction() {
        // Do something
    }
}

fun <T : A> T.myCustomApply(block: T.() -> Unit): T {
    this.block()
    // Do something else
    return this
}
```

But I personnally think this is not a good idea, because it confuses the code (where does the myCustomApply come from ? Why isn't it in class A ?), and is a bit complicated for such a simple problem. You're free to think this is a good solution, but I don't really agree.

My idea was to do something like this (don't try this in your IDE, it will just complain that you're the worst developper ever and that you doesn't even deserve to exist because it isn't actual syntax) :

```
abstract class A {
    fun myCustomApply(block: this.() -> Unit): this {
        block()
        // Do something else
        return this
    }
}

class B : A() {
    fun anotherFunction() {
        // Do something
    }
}

fun doSomethingVeryUseful(): B {
    val b = B()
    return b.myCustomApply {
        anotherFunction()  // YEAH
    }
}
```

Note that `this` is used in two places : as a receiver type and as a return type.
As `this` already is a keyword, it wouldn't break any existing code, so backward compatibility is assured.

`this` as a type would have a single accepted value, that is, `this`. Why use `this` as a type ? This will garantee to the compiler that the value is effectively of the type of the receiver, that is `b.myCustomApply` now accepts a lambda of type `B.() -> Unit`, and has a return type of type B, since `b` itself is of type B.

Another (purely aesthetic) advantage would be that it is now clear that the same object (that is, the receiver) will be passed to the lambda, and then returned to the caller of the method.

This would translate to something like this :

```
abstract class A<_this : A<_this>> {
    private fun _this(): _this =
         @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (this as _this)        
    
    fun myCustomApply(block: _this.() -> Unit): _this {
        _this().block()
        // You got the idea
        return _this()
    }
}

class B : A<B>() {
    fun anotherFunction() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The `_this` type parameter's name is pretty self-explaining of its role, if A already has type parameters then _this should be added at the beggining of them, and any type expression of the form A<T, U, V, ...> should expand to A<A, T, U, V, ...>.

`this` as return type would require that `return this` and `return /* something that has this as type */` are the only `return` statements that are allowed, as we couldn't ensure that any other value is actually always of the same type as `this`.

I propose `this` (what a great pun huh) because it has been several times that I felt a need for such a feature, but I'm unsure whether this is a good idea or not, if it is feasible, and if there actually are people that are interested.

In either cases, thank you for reading, have a great day !

Comment: Hi - are you asking for help in solving something? It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. It seems you have a workaround (though I think it can be improved with generics). But first can you read the StackOverflow guidelines on how to ask questions, and then update your post? If you want to propose a new Kotlin feature, have you searched on JetBrains YouTrack? Lastly, improvements to receivers are coming, you might be interested:https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42435

Comment: SO is a question and answer site. You are not asking a question, you are proposing a language feature. The Kotlin open source project and / or slack group would be a better place for this.

Comment: Ahh, so now you edited the question to add "my" answer to it, so my answer looks pretty silly. Great.

Comment: Thanks for your answers (which aren't really answers because my question wasn't really a question). I see that this already has been asked for (and it doesn't surprises me), so I won't ask it at the link ASemy sent (but thanks !). I forgot Stackoverflow was only here to ask questions, so I'll just suppress this because it was rather a proposal (I just wanted to know you opinion about it) !

Comment: I’m voting to close this because  it's not a question, and would better fit in a Kotlin discussion forum

Answer (score 3):

On thread ["Self Types"](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371), from Andrey Breslav, [lead language designer for Kotlin](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/breslav.html), in December 2014:

> Unfortunately, self types turn out to be a challenge when it comes to type system design. We don't see a sane way of implementing them at the moment

See also:

- ["This type"](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/this-type/1421), an adjacent forum thread
- ["Emulating self types in Kotlin"](https://medium.com/@jerzy.chalupski/emulating-self-types-in-kotlin-d64fe8ea2e62), a Medium post by Jerzy Chałupski

Answer (score 1):

It does not really answer your question (assuming there was any question at all), but note you can do something like this:

```kotlin
abstract class A<T : A<T>> {
    fun myCustomApply(block: T.() -> Unit): T {
        (this as T).block()  // block() would have the same effect
        // Do something else here
        return this
    }
}

class B : A<B>() { ... }
```

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer in order to add this under-the-hood implementation rather than the original one (which was cumbersome), because I had the same idea. I don't really like this implementation, because this adds code complexity (plus a `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` might be needed before the `this as T` expression in order to avoid a compiler warning, and `return (@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (this as T))` should be used as well) and turns out to be quite difficult to read when the code gets bigger. But thanks for this proposal !